# Add my-events link to buddypress admin bar?

Tags: buddypress

In the Buddypress site I'm working on, I was asked to add a direct link to "my-events" to the admin bar, as it will be the feature used most often by this site's admin. What is the correct way to get the link to this page? I think I'm looking for something like this, but it didn't work:

```
 get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'events/my-events' ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct link to my-events for who ? 
The admin?  The displayed user ?

This should add an admin link for the displayed user - or at least get you started.
Put it in plugins/bp-custom.php

```
function add_my_events_link() { 
    global $bp;
    if ( !is_super_admin() || bp_is_my_profile() || !$bp->displayed_user->id )
        return false;
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( $bp->displayed_user->domain . 'events/my-events/', 'my-events' ) ?>" class="confirm"><?php printf( __( "My Events for ", 'buddypress' ), esc_attr( $bp->displayed_user->fullname ) ) ?></a></li>
<?php
}
add_action( 'bp_adminbar_menus', 'add_my_events_link', 20 );
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I meant for the admin. There is one admin user who will be creating all the events for this site. The admin bar will be hidden for all other users, anyway. That should help, though, I just need to find the logged-in user equivalent to $bp->displayed_user